# Slow recursion even with memoization in R

Tags: r, recursion, memoization, collatz

I'm trying to solve the problem [#14 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14).
So the main objective is finding length of Collatz sequence.

Firstly I solved problem with regular loop:

```r
compute <- function(n) {
    result <- 0
    max_chain <- 0
    hashmap <- 1
    for (i in 1:n) {
        chain <- 1
        number <- i
        while (number > 1) {
            if (!is.na(hashmap[number])) {
                chain <- chain + hashmap[number]
                break
            }
            if (number %% 2 == 0) {
                chain <- chain + 1
                number <- number / 2
            } else {
                chain <- chain + 2
                number <- (3 * number + 1) / 2
            }
        }
        hashmap[i] <- chain
        if (chain > max_chain) {
            max_chain <- chain
            result <- i
        }
    }
    return(result)
}
```

Only 2 seconds for `n = 1000000`.
I decided to replace while loop to recursion

```r
len_collatz_chain <- function(n, hashmap) {
    get_len <- function(n) {
        if (is.na(hashmap[n])) {
            hashmap[n] <<- ifelse(n %% 2 == 0, 1 + get_len(n / 2), 2 + get_len((3 * n + 1) / 2))
        }
        return(hashmap[n])
    }
    get_len(n)
    return(hashmap)
}

compute <- function(n) {
    result <- 0
    max_chain <- 0
    hashmap <- 1
    for (i in 1:n) {
        hashmap <- len_collatz_chain(i, hashmap)
        print(length(hashmap))
        if (hashmap[i] > max_chain) {
            max_chain <- hashmap[i]
            result <- i
        }
    }
    return(result)
}
```

This solution works but works so slow. Almost 1 min for `n = 10000`.
I suppose that one of the reasons is R creates `hashmap` object each time when call function `len_collatz_chain`.

I know about Rcpp packages and yes, the first solution works fine but I can't understand where I'm wrong.
Any tips?

For example, my Python recursive solution works in 1 second with `n = 1000000`

```py
def len_collatz_chain(n: int, hashmap: dict) -> int:
    if n not in hashmap:
        hashmap[n] = 1 + len_collatz_chain(n // 2, hashmap) if n % 2 == 0 else 2 + len_collatz_chain((3 * n + 1) // 2, hashmap)
    return hashmap[n]

def compute(n: int) -> int:
    result, max_chain, hashmap = 0, 0, {1: 1}
    for i in range(2, n):
        chain = len_collatz_chain(i, hashmap)
        if chain > max_chain:
            result, max_chain = i, chain
    return result
```

Comment: I believe its all the overhead stack issue within R. If you want to stick with R, I bet you use the Rcpp as you claimed

Comment: Or you could just run your python code in R using Reticulate package

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between your R and Python code is that in R you use a vector for the hashmap, while in Python you use a dictionary and that hashmap is transferred many times as function argument.

In Python, if you have a Dictionary as function argument, only a **reference** to the actual data is transfered to the called function. This is fast. The called function works on the same data as the caller.

In R, a vector is **copied** when used as function argument. This is potentially slow, but safer in the sense that the called function cannot alter the data of the caller.

This the main reason that Python is so much faster in your code.

You can however alter the R code slightly, such that the hashmap is not transfered as function argument anymore:

```
len_collatz_chain <- local({
  
  hashmap <- 1L
  
  get_len <- function(n) {
    if (is.na(hashmap[n])) {
      hashmap[n] <<- ifelse(n %% 2 == 0, 1 + get_len(n / 2), 2 + get_len((3 * n + 1) / 2))
    }
    hashmap[n]
  }
  
  get_len
})


compute <- function(n) {
  result <- rep(NA_integer_, n)
  
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    result[i] <- len_collatz_chain(i)
  }
  result
}

compute(n=10000)
```

This makes the R code much faster. (Python will probably still be faster though).

Note that I have also removed the `return` statements in the R code, as they are not needed and add one level to the call stack.

Comment: If i right, in your solution the `hashmap` object will creates each time in for loop. But then memoization doesn't work.

Comment: No, you're wrong here. The hashmap object will only be created once in my solution and even persists between different `compute()` calls. Make a test and call `compute(n=10000)` two times. The second time the answer is instant, because `hashmap` is even persisted bewteen calls in its closure.
So memoization works.

Comment: If you look closely at my code, you can see that `len_collatz_chain` is the function `get_len` plus its closure. It returns the function `get_len`. So everytime `len_collatz_chain()` is called, the function that is actually called is `get_len()`. The `hashmap` object is only created once when `len_collatz_chain` is initialized, but not on every call of `get_len`, abd thus not in every iteration of the for-loop! :)